# Delete a specific private key from an Electrum 3.3.8 wallet via the command line?

Tags: private-key, electrum, command-line-options, cli

I imported a few private keys into my electrum wallet via the command line. Now I want to delete these specific private keys from electrum 3.3.8 - What is the command to delete these keys from my wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `importprivkey()` with electrum it makes you create a new wallet for the key import. You can't do it on the command line but you can delete the wallet file from your PC (assuming that new wallet you created during import only has that key on it).

```
   C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Roaming\Electrum\wallets
```

Comment: I need to do it on the command line as I'm using electrum as a service.